# How to improve for loop interation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to add a new column where i'll classificate if in this row my outlet temperature was low, normal or high (with 1 milion rows in my data frame).

To do this, i use a for iteration with multif's for classificate each row like this way: low temp (lower than 61), normal temp (between 61 and 64) and high temp (higher than 64). However, this 1 million iterations is too have and it takes so long that i think my PC freeze and needs to shutdown the spyder IDE.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xlrd
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
def read_date(date):
    return xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(date, 0)
data1 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Dados1_14a26_maio.txt', sep=r'\t', engine='python')
data1 = data1.drop('Descartar',axis=1)
data2 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Dados2_14a26_maio.txt', sep=r'\t', engine='python')
data3 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Dados3_14a26_maio.txt', sep=r'\t', engine='python')
data3 = data3.drop(['Descartar','Descartar.1','Descartar.2','Descartar.3','Descartar.4','Descartar.5','Descartar.6','Descartar.7','Descartar.8'],axis=1)
DataHora = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Hora'])
DataHora['Hora'] = pd.to_datetime(DataHora['Hora'].apply(read_date), errors='coerce')
data_in = [data1.TentHT, data2.NumVentOn, data3.Tamb]
entrada = pd.concat(data_in, axis=1)
data_out = [data1.TsaidaHT]
saida = pd.concat(data_out, axis=1)
pca_matriz = pd.concat([entrada, saida], axis=1)
cond = pd.DataFrame()
Status = pd.Series([])
for x in saida.index:
    if saida.TsaidaHT[x] < 61: 
        Status[x] = "Low"
    elif saida.TsaidaHT[x] >= 61 and saida.TsaidaHT[x] <= 64: 
        Status[x] = "Normal"
    elif saida.TsaidaHT[x] > 64: 
        Status[x] = "High"
cond.insert(0,"Status",Status)
```

I want to know if there's a way to make this for and multi if's iteration faster so as not to freeze my pc.

Comment: You can do in parts. First do half of the records and then do second half. You can also try writing the function and then use .apply(function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy.select` for this - it is better optimized. Took around 2-3 seconds for me to run the below with 1 million dummy records.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from random import randint

d = {"temp":[randint(1,100) for _ in range(1000000)]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df["Status"] = np.select([df["temp"]<61, df["temp"]>64],
                         ["Low","High"],
                         default="Normal")
df.tail()
```

Result:

```
        temp  Status
999995     8     Low
999996    62  Normal
999997    40     Low
999998     3     Low
999999    48     Low
```

Comment: Thanks, Henry! It Works perfectly for my application!